# AngularJS Custom Components- via E2E

Tags: angularjs

How can we make different components in angular-javascipts that consist of URL, template,controller,CSS and load them via E2E as when needed?

Comment: What do you mean by E2E? Element or Attribute Components are made in Angular1 using Directives.

Comment: E2E is end to end testing @JinsPeter